# Tool(s) "patch" is(are) missed, please install it(them)

Tags: windows-8, bash, cygwin

I am using xampp in Windows 8. I want to install magento security patches in local magetno. To run command I have install [Cvgdrive](https://cygwin.com) but when I run the following command I am getting an error.

```
bash PATCH_SUPEE-5388_CE_1.4.0.0-1.5.0.1_v1-2015-03-03-09-43-19.sh
```

The error:

> Error! Some required system tools, that are utilized in this sh script, are not installed:
>       Tool(s) "patch" is(are) missed, please install it(them).

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The command line utility `patch` needs to be installed. Cygwin has a **package** system to install additional utilities and programs for use in the Cygwin environment.

1. [Full list of Cygwin packages](https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html) is here.
2. [Cygwin Package Search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi) for full package version name.
3. [Installing and updating Cygwin packages](https://cygwin.com/install.html)

Run the Cygwin setup program (`setup-x86.exe` or `setup-x86_64.exe`) to manage what's installed.